# Remove double quotes from javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I have tried everything possible and nothing seems to work. I am using [Bootstrap Data Table](http://wenzhixin.net.cn/p/bootstrap-table/docs/index.html) to generate my table. I want to be able to check a box click a delete button and the send the data to php using ajax.

Everything works except deleting the user because it is adding double quotes to the data string in the url when it gets passed to the php file.

Here is the JS code:

```
.on('check.bs.table', function (e, row) {
            $result.text('Are you sure you want to delete ' + JSON.stringify(row.username) + '?');
            var ids = document.getElementById("user-id").value =  JSON.stringify(row.id);
            ids = ids.replace (/\"/g, "");
        })
```

No matter what I do it always includes the double quotes for the ids `var`.

Can someone please give me some suggestions?

Comment: Please check the `var` line, it has two `=`s, then think about the executing order of that `var` and the next line ...

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Bootstrap Data Table, but if you can see the value of `ids` in an URL, it has to come from the `#user-id.value`, since `ids` is a local variable to the event handler. JS passes everything by value, and the value of `#user-id` won't magically change, if you change the value of `ids` _after_ putting it to `#user-id`.

Comment: Why are you calling  `JSON.stringify(row.id)`? That adds quotes around your string

Comment: @JuanMendes I just posted the answer below before the comment. I wish you were here when i originally posted my question lol.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the comments!

After doing a little more research I was able to fix my issue. The problem was - I am using `JSON.stringify` which turns my id into a string therefore adding `""` around it. To prevent this from happening I simply remove `JSON.stringify`

Here is what I changed:
`document.getElementById("user-id").value =  row.id;`

So the end code looks like this:

```
.on('check.bs.table', function (e, row) {
        $result.text('Are you sure you want to delete ' + JSON.stringify(row.username) + '?');
        document.getElementById("user-id").value =  row.id;
    })
```

Comment: This is a better solution, as I suggested in the comments. But in the spirit of understanding what was wrong... You were expecting  `ids = ids.replace (/\"/g, "");` to update the DOM value that you set in the line above. It would have worked if you had done your replace before setting the form value.